# Combine Python List and Dict comprehension with counter

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I want to transfer a list of tuples:

```
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

to a list of `dict` (in order to create a pandas dataframe) which looks like:

```
[{'index':1, 'match':1},{'index':1, 'match':3},{'index':1, 'match':5},
{'index':2, 'match':2}, {'index':2, 'match':4},{'index':2, 'match':6},
{'index':3, 'match':7},{'index':3, 'match':8},{'index':3, 'match':9}]
```

For performance reasons I wanted to use a list and dict comprehension:

```
[{'index':ind, 'match': } for ind, s in enumerate(test_set, 1)]
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: that is a list of tuples you have there; not sets.

Comment: You say performance matters. In that case a nested for loop without comprehension would do, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Elmex80s: you can use nested for loops in list comprehension.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes you are right, but it is something I would try to avoid, IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use *list comprehension* use a second `for` to loop over the `'match'`es:

```
[{'index':ind, 'match':match} for ind,s in enumerate(test_set,1) for match in s]
```

So the second `for` loop iterates over the elements in the tuples and for each of these elements, a dictionary is generated and added to the result.

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what i was looking for.